# Python: Help me understand how it can be possible

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Please help me understand how key variable can have a value a or b?

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict = defaultdict(list)
group_a_count, group_b_count = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(1, group_a_count + 1):
    dict[input()].append(i)

for i in range(1, group_b_count + 1):
    key = input()
    print(key)

INPUT: 
5 2
a
a
b
a
b
a
b


OUTPUT:
a
b
```

All input values was appended to dictonary in first cycle. And how second cycle understood where to get keys from the dictonary?

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. The second loop *also* gets the values from the input. What makes you think otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit messy code. The only thing the second loop does, is asking group_b_count times an input, which it then prints and continues with the next iteration... So the output is a and b because of this piece of code:

```
key = input()
print(key)
```

which just prints what you gave as input

What's the purpose of this program actually?

Comment: It's a part of decision from DefaultDict Tutorial from HackerRank.

Answer (score 0):

And if i use for cycle with this parameters:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    key = input()
    print(key)
```

in STDOUT will be still a and b. A full purpose of program: "In this challenge, you will be given 2 integers, n and m. There are n words, which might repeat, in word group A. There are m words belonging to word group B. For each m words, check whether the word has appeared in group A or not. Print the indices of each occurrence of m in group A. If it does not appear, print -1."

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood task from HackerRank and I expected another output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).